# How to sum range of values if date =specific date but keep result fixed next day?

Tags: google-sheets

If I want to sum of dynamic cell values (numbers) across range if date is specific (like 2 Feb 2021) and keep the maximum result fixed so I can draw a chart of percent reached.. Like elections for example..
If i type: sumif(A1:A2,C2=2/Feb/2021)

Comment: SUMIF(C1:C2,DATE(2021,2,2),A1:A2)

Comment: Thanks. But the sum result will be zero if the date is not 2,2,2021. For example lets do it like this. `SUMIF(C1:C2,TODAY(),A1:A2)` . So tomorrow the result will be zero. How to keep the result as it was on TODAY() 23:59 as it is the last chance to enter data. and keep it fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by adding a helper column that will ass the date.time automatically based on OnEdit trigger of a range of cells or column. Then you could countif range based on specific date criteria in that helper column. Thanks to @Rubén